# windows failed to do system reset. all files lost

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, system-restore

I tried to do a system reset on my windows 10 PC. I left it overnight since it said it had about 8 hours to go. when I cam into work the PC said that the system reset had failed. I clicked ok and the PC automatically began a restart. when it started up everything that I had was gone. I imagine that there has to be a folder someplace with my data in it since the system reset was supposed to retain my files. I just do not know how to get them back. Please help.to be more specific. everything i had on the pc is gone. files programs pictures everything. when i did the reset i chose keep all files and when it failed to reset properly it seems to have deleted my user accounts from before along with all my files and everything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The only place your files would be (if there) is in Windows.old (root folder of C:).  Also open Start. Settings, Update and see if you can roll back (probably not).

Comment: to be more specific. everything i had on the pc is gone. files programs pictures everything. when i did the reset i chose keep all files and when it failed to reset properly it seems to have deleted my user accounts from before along with all my files and everything

Comment: I hope you have some backups. What you describe only happens when the operating system becomes damaged beyond repair.

Comment: i wouldnt be asking for help if i had an external backup. the pc was only supposed to do a /reset/restor and keep all my information. i dont know what happened but that didnt.

Comment: @Richard - You obviously did NOT select the option to keep your personal files, if your personal files, no longer exist on your system.  If the files do not exist in `Windows.old` then they do not exist on your system.  If you had selected that option your personal files would not have been deleted.  Sadly, if you don't have a backup of your personal files, there really isn't anything we can do about that fact.

Comment: no I am very certain I DID select keep my files. Like i said. there was some form of error during the reset. i also know that there is almost always a way to recover data. so if there is anyone that CAN help me i would greatly appreciate that instead of people telling me that they hope i made a backup or that i did not do what i am certain i DID do.

Comment: Unbelievable - you restored your computer to factory condition without first taking a backup???? The most you can now do is try recovery products such as: [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva), [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk),[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). DON'T boot with this computer - take the disk out and do everything on another computer.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake. no need to try to make me feel stupid. i did a pc reset which was supposed to keep all my files. it did not work properly and now i lost everything. i feel like this is enough without people here trying to make me feel like an idiot. you know more than me...thats great. thats why i am here to ask for help. i did not come here to be talked down to

Comment: If you do the reset and choose to keep your files, it indeed _should_ keep your files. Unfortunately that's a bit of a central theme in IT world... "this should work". That's why we do backups, which most of us learn the hard way at one point or another. And at some point we learn to make backups of backups... There's really not much left to do except follow @harrymc:s advice _to the letter_. Booting the 'puter with that drive is a good way to lose everything permanently.

Comment: i definitely learned the hard way on this one. first time it has happened. i will be making a backup of whatever i am able to recover. thank you for the assistance

Comment: I apologize if you think I was talking down to you, I didn't mean to. If it would help, each of us here, including myself, had his times for beating on the table and shouting "stupid" at oneself. You could try the utilities I recommended in the way I recommended, or contact a data-recovery company (not cheap). The lesson in the future would be not to believe promises by programs (not even mine).

Comment: We are all trying to help. For your future reference, I keep a general file store and a general document store. Both are very large. I run Sync Back Pro 2 or 3 times a day to ensure important documents are on another computer if either one goes south on me. Things learned from experience.

Comment: "if there is anyone that CAN help me" - If you selected the option to keep your personal files, then the files would either be in their original location or contained within Windows.old, you have not indicate if you have looked within Windows.old for your files.  Outside of that, standard data recovery software will have to be used, but since you likely overwrote your data that is a longshot.

Comment: i do not know where to find windows.old   i did a search on my c: drive and could not find it

Comment: also the recovery programs are any of them free that will work. i dont have a lot of money right now. also when you say to not use data recovery tool while drive is in computer...will leaving it in the computer keep me from being able to recover info

Comment: Windows.old is right on the root of your C drive. That's where it always is.